# Google network architecture

Tags: networking, load-balancing, high-availability, google, architecture

I am aware that this question might be closed as "not a real question", "subjective" or even "argumentative". If this is a mistake, I am sorry.

I am not good at all at networking but I'm trying to get better and learn more. (you might know the saying : "the first step to intelligence is acknowledging that you are stupid" :P).

Network-wise what happens after I type www.google.com in my browser and press enter?

Here's what I know so far :

- The browser application makes a DNS
  request to find the IP of
  www.google.com. It might find
  209.85.148.105 (that's what has just been resolved for me now).
- Then it connects via TCP/IP to that host on port 80 (default port for HTTP) and sends an HTTP request like GET /
- Receives HTML data and displays it (along with loading additional resources such as .css, images files etc.)

**What I want to find out is how it connects, step by step, to a Google server**. After the request goes out of my computer and my ISP it finally hits google hardware at some point.

- Is there a load balancer?
- **How many of them?**
- **Are there multiple levels of load balancers? i.e.: a load balancer of load balancers of load balancers...**
- **How powerful is an end web server? Could it be a lousy 500 MHz CPU machine with 512MB RAM and 10 GB HDD? Or maybe an 8-core, 16GB, RAID-0 SSD beast?**
- What kind of redundancy do they use at network level?
- **What happens if load balancer(s) fail?**
- **What does it take to make www.google.com unavailable? (No, I don't want to sabotage or sth..)**

Comment: its all about the tubes dude, just big tubes.

Comment: I'll contribute a small portion: their DNS servers check the location of a requester before sending an answer, and return a list of web servers that are geographically appropriate.

Comment: @Shane Madden, post it as a (partial) answer so I can upvote it. It is worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out http://highscalability.com/display/Search?searchQuery=google it's full of resources.

Comment: +1 - I'd never seen that site before. Some excellent info in there. Cheers for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Google's hardware, this is a great place to [start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform).

There's also some stuff on topology/load balancing there.